# Printing arrays with different lengths

Tags: java, arrays, printing, double

I'm writing a program that prints an array containing the sum of the values of two arrays passed as parameters. I need to include exceptions for when one of the arrays may be longer than the other. In that case, the method should print the sum of the indexes that both arrays share, then print the values of the array that don't have a corresponding value to add to.

The problem here is that every time I go to compile the program, I get a message that says:
Sum.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable sumY
location: class Sum
                    sumY[j] = x[j] + y[j];
                    ^
1 error

```
import java.util.*;

class Sum
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        double [] a1 = {4.5, 2.8, 3.4, 0.8};
        double [] a2 = {1.4, 8.9, -1.0, 2.3};

        arraySum (a1, a2);

        System.out.println (Arrays.toString (arraySum (a1, a2)));   
    }

    public static double [] arraySum (double [] x, double [] y)
    {
        int length = 0;

        if (x.length < y.length)
        {
            double [] sumY = new double [y.length];
            length = y.length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= y.length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j <= x.length-1; j++)
                {
                    sumY [j] = x[j] + y[j];
                }

                sumY [(x.length -1) + i] = y[i];
            }

            return sumY;        
        }

        if (x.length > y.length)
        {
            double [] sumX = new double [x.length];
            length = x.length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j <= y.length-1; j++)
                {
                    sumY[j] = x[j] + y[j];
                }

                sumX [(y.length -1) + i] = y[i];
            }

            return sumX;
        }

        else
        {
            double [] sum = new double [x.length];
            length = x.length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
            {
                sum[i] = x[i] + y[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions.  Could you please make them separate questions?  Otherwise, it's possible that one person will supply the best answer for one question, and somebody else will supply the best answer for the other; and you'll be unable to reward them both appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

1: Instead of using Arrays.toString, use

```
System.out.printf("[");
double[] sum = arraySum(a1, a2);
for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%0.1f", sum[i]);
    if(i != sum.length - 1) {
        System.out.printf(", ");
    }
}
System.out.printf("]\n");
```

2: In the second if block, you're using sumY where I gather you mean sumX. sumY is not defined in that scope, so it's giving you an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the code shorter by implementing a method. In this case I called it `altMethod`. Also, you should notice that the `altMethod` does not use a `for` loop **within** a `for` loop but rather one followed by another. First one fills in the sums while the indexes can be paired up, the next one just fills in the indexes of the ones that are left.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MySum {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        double [] a1 = {4.5, 2.8, 3.4, 0.8};
        double [] a2 = {1.4, 8.9, -1.0, 2.4};

        System.out.println (Arrays.toString (arraySum(a1, a2)));   
    }

    public static double [] arraySum (double [] x, double [] y) {

        if (x.length < y.length) {
            return altMethod(x, y);
        }

        if (x.length > y.length) {
            return altMethod(y, x);
        }

        else {
            return altMethod(x, y);
        }

    }

    public static double[] altMethod(double[] smaller, double[] bigger) {
        int length = 0;
        double[] answer = new double[bigger.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < smaller.length ; i++) {
            answer[i] = smaller[i] + bigger[i];
            length++;
        }

        for(;length < bigger.length; length++) {
            answer[length] = bigger[length];
        }

        return answer;
    }
}
```

The `altMethod` does have to take arguments in certain order though. Being `(smaller, bigger)` but not the other way around `(bigger, smaller)`.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit SkyLuke :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the closest `double` to 2.3 and the closest `double` to 0.8, when added together, do NOT give the closest `double` to 3.1.

If you're going to do arithmetic with exact decimals, and expect the right answers, you should use the `BigDecimal` class instead of `double`.

Comment: off topic question @David, what's that symbol you're using as an avatar man? Cause the thing is, I am Egyptian and it means a huge big thingy in here and ... it's interesting to see a guy named David, from New Zealand using that logo :D

Comment: @AhmadAlfy If you're Egyptian, then why are you asking me what the Rabia sign is?  You know what it is!  Peace be upon you, my brother.

Comment: Peace be upon you brother :) was just making sure :)